# Easy fix for not showing 0 counts in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have made this query where I count how many new inserts in each hour. The problem is that my query will not show the hours without new entries.

How do I fix this in an easy way?

```
SELECT
count(HOUR(delivered))as count,
CASE 
    WHEN HOUR(delivered) = 0 THEN '0'
    WHEN HOUR(delivered) = 1 THEN '1'
    WHEN HOUR(delivered) = 2 THEN '2'
    WHEN HOUR(delivered) = 3 THEN '3'
    WHEN HOUR(delivered) = 4 THEN '4'
    WHEN HOUR(delivered) = 5 THEN '5'
    WHEN HOUR(delivered) = 6 THEN '6'
    WHEN HOUR(delivered) = 7 THEN '7'
    WHEN HOUR(delivered) = 8 THEN '8'
    WHEN HOUR(delivered) = 9 THEN '9'
    WHEN HOUR(delivered) = 10 THEN '10'
    WHEN HOUR(delivered) = 11 THEN '11'
    WHEN HOUR(delivered) = 12 THEN '12'
    WHEN HOUR(delivered) = 13 THEN '13'
    WHEN HOUR(delivered) = 14 THEN '14'
    WHEN HOUR(delivered) = 15 THEN '15'
    WHEN HOUR(delivered) = 16 THEN '16'
    WHEN HOUR(delivered) = 17 THEN '17'
    WHEN HOUR(delivered) = 18 THEN '18'
    WHEN HOUR(delivered) = 19 THEN '19'
    WHEN HOUR(delivered) = 20 THEN '20'
    WHEN HOUR(delivered) = 21 THEN '21'
    WHEN HOUR(delivered) = 22 THEN '22'
    WHEN HOUR(delivered) = 23 THEN '23'

END AS intervals
FROM
    Wardrobe_CloakTable
WHERE
    payingcustomerID = 2
    AND DAY(delivered) = 09
    AND MONTH(delivered) = 09
    AND YEAR(delivered) = 2016
GROUP BY intervals
```

Comment: do you have a datetime row in your table? Something like this? `2015-10-19 16:17:33`

Comment: add a hour table (derived (`select 0 union select 2`...)  or actual) and left join it to wardrobe_cloaktable. on hour delivered.  this way you have all 24 hours in the derived table and 0 counts can be displayed.  you'll have to `coalesce` your count so that if it's null it will return 0.

Comment: delivered is DATETIME

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start with a table containing values betweeen 0 and 23, and left join your data table.

**Edit:** Let's try changing `COUNT(delivered)` to `SUM(delivered IS NOT NULL)` to see if we can get a numeric value on every row.

Let's start by simplifying your query.  This will come in handy in a moment, because we have to use it to make a bigger query.

```
            SELECT SUM(delivered IS NOT NULL) AS count,
                   HOUR(delivered) AS intervals
              FROM Wardrobe_CloakTable
             WHERE payingcustomerID = 2
               AND delivered >= '2016-09-09'
               AND delivered <  '2016-09-09' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
             GROUP BY HOUR(delivered)
```

(By the way, an index on `(payingcustomerID, delivered)` will make this query very fast.)

Now we need a little virtual table with numbers 0 - 23.  This will do the trick: it uses JOIN combinatorials to generate 2 x 2 x 2 x 3 integers.  We'll call this little table `seq_0_to_23`.  Why? because these [sequence tables](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/sequence/) are built in to the [MariaDB](https://mariadb.org/) fork of MySQL.

```
          SELECT A.N + 2*(B.N + 2*(C.N +2*(D.N))) AS seq
            FROM (SELECT 0 AS N UNION SELECT 1) AS A
            JOIN (SELECT 0 AS N UNION SELECT 1) AS B
            JOIN (SELECT 0 AS N UNION SELECT 1) AS C
            JOIN (SELECT 0 AS N UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2) AS D
```

Finally, you use a LEFT JOIN, like this.

```
SELECT SUM(delivered IS NOT NULL) AS count,
       seq AS intervals
 FROM (
                SELECT A.N + 2*(B.N + 2*(C.N +2*(D.N))) AS seq
                  FROM (SELECT 0 AS N UNION SELECT 1) AS A
                  JOIN (SELECT 0 AS N UNION SELECT 1) AS B
                  JOIN (SELECT 0 AS N UNION SELECT 1) AS C
                  JOIN (SELECT 0 AS N UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2) AS D
       ) seq_0_to_23
  LEFT JOIN Wardrobe_CloakTable ON HOUR(delivered) = seq
 WHERE payingcustomerID = 2
   AND delivered >= '2016-09-09'
   AND delivered <  '2016-09-09' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
 GROUP BY seq
 ORDER BY seq
```

This uses the sequence table as a source of all the hours of the day, then pulls in matching values from your actual data.

If you're using MariaDB, this looks like so. As you can see, the built in sequence table make the query look much more elegant.

```
SELECT SUM(delivered IS NOT NULL) AS count,
       seq AS intervals
  FROM seq_0_to_23
  LEFT JOIN Wardrobe_CloakTable ON HOUR(delivered) = seq
 WHERE payingcustomerID = 2
   AND delivered >= '2016-09-09'
   AND delivered <  '2016-09-09' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
 GROUP BY seq
 ORDER BY seq
```

We're using `SELECT SUM(delivered IS NOT NULL)` because we need numeric results in the aggregate function for every row.  `delivered IS NOT NULL` gives back either 1 or 0, so the `SUM()` should work nicely.

Here's a [comprehensive explanation of this technique.](http://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/filling-missing-data-sequences-cardinal-integers/)

Comment: sorry for the quite late answer, went home from work friday. But this look exactly like what i need. im using innoDB but the 2nd query is not giving what i want, its giving me only the intervals with values in. Like the complicated query i had